# Floating up an element if the previous one left enough space with css

Tags: css

I create this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/revayati/1/edit?html,css,output) to picture my problem, for some reason I'm thinking that when you float element they could go up as long as they have enough space. But I'm missing something or I'm completly wrong about it. Why is that the darkviolet square doesn't go up?

Update for @paulie and anyone who prefer not to see a jsbin or jsfiddle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block double">
    </div><div class="block next">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div><div class="block">
    </div>    
  </div>

</body>
</html>

.container {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 600px;
    width: 306px;
    position: relative;
}
.block { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative
}
.block:nth-child(3n + 2) {
    background-color: green;
}
.block:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    background-color: blue;
}
.block:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: red;
}
.block.double {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px; 
}
.block.next {
    background-color: darkviolet;
    float: right;

}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML & CSS in your original question.

Comment: It doesn't go up because there are elements above and the width is fixed to `306px`.[Example](http://jsbin.com/revayati/4/edit)